How to highlight traces on legend hover events
I'm plotting lines from variable data, the items can sometimes have identical data points so need a way to see which lines are stacked. I'd like to implement something similar to the mplcursors highlight feature which highlights figures as you hover them in the legend.
In Seaborn using dodge on a catplot works quite well to show that you're not looking at a single line. I ended up using Plotly because it has has some nice defaults like hover annotations and show/hide figures by clicking the corresponding legend item. I've tried mplcursors with Seaborn to add hover annotations but it seems buggy.
The bottom line in the following screenshot has all of the items in the legend stacked except the other two. I can click through the legend until I've removed the top two to know which ones are stacked but it's not very efficient.

The code currently looks like this:
    df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_dict_for_dataframe)

    dfm = df.melt('Date', var_name='Item', value_name='Price')

    fig = px.line(dfm, x="Date", y="Price", color='Item', markers=True)
    fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
    fig.show()


Without a minimally reproducible example, it's very difficult to provide any specific coding help. However, I can tell you that you can add a Plotly event to accomplish this task. For example, look here or look here for ways others have implemented this in Python.

This is the example given in the mplcursors github issues section
